# Problem with R package COMPoissonReg for Conway-Maxwell Poisson regression

Tags: r, poisson

I am trying to use the function `cmp` from the package `COMPoissonReg` to run a Conway-Maxwell Poisson regression on some heavily under-dispersed insurance mortality data and I get the following error

```
Error in xmat %*% par[1:length(betainit)] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

The function seems to begin to work and produces estimates for the coefficients but then it fails and generates the error.

My code is in the following format

```
COMform = DeathCount ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + offset(log(exposure))
COMMod <- cmp(formula = COMform, data = df)
```

I have run a standard Poisson regression on the same data and predictors and everything runs just fine. Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: probably unanswerable without a reproducible example: see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 . You could try `options(error=recover)`, which will dump you into debug mode (see `?debug`) when you encounter an error ...

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide a reproducible example as my data is proprietary. I just tested the function on some sample data and it works without issue.

Comment: you'll either have to debug it yourself, then, or find a way to scramble/anonymize your data appropriately, or keep working to come up with sample data that do demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I encountered same problem as well, guess it doesn't support `offset`

Comment: Actually, the package is just a small demo for author's paper. It is not optimized for R at all and not providing with many useful features dedicated in R. But on the flip side, the source code is very readable.